# Est-ce que « nombreux » est un déterminant indéfini ?

Tags: grammaire, déterminants

> certains étudiants / de nombreux étudiants

Question : *Certains* et *nombreux* sont-ils des déterminants indéfinis ?

Answer (score 3):

Les deux mots concernés, *certains* et *nombreux* n'appartiennent pas à la même catégorie (en tout cas dans l'usage proposé).
Le deuxième est un simple adjectif classique qui peut occuper différentes positions et être modifié par *très* :

- épithète : *les (très) nombreux étudiants* ou *les étudiants (très) nombreux à sourire*
- attribut : *les étudiants sont (très) nombreux*

Le premier ne peut occuper aucune de ces deux positions et ne peut pas être modifié par *très* :

- épithète : *les (?très?) ?certains? étudiants* ou *les étudiants #certains#*
- attribut : *les étudiants sont #certains#*

NB. *#certains#* a un sens différent.

En résumé, *nombreux* est un adjectif. Pour *certains*, les terminologies varient mais on peut le rapprocher d'autres termes qui ont la même distribution (quelques, plusieurs, ...) et qui n'ont par exemple pas de singulier contrairement aux adjectifs (*un public nombreux*, *une foule nombreuse*). S'il faut choisir parmi les catégories classiques (nom, verbe, adjectif, adverbe, conjonction, préposition, déterminant), c'est plutôt un déterminant.

Answer (score -1):

Oui, alias *adjectifs indéfinis*.

Comment: Ils n'appartiennent pas à la même catégorie...

Comment: Je n'ai pas dit que les adjectifs et les déterminants sont pareils, mais les adjectifs indéfinis font partie des déterminants. 

Du Petit Robert :

    déterminant - spécialt - Membre de la classe de morphèmes grammaticaux portant les marques du genre et du nombre du nom qu'ils actualisent (articles, adjectifs possessifs, démonstratifs, indéfinis, numéraux, interrogatifs…).

Comment: Tout à fait d'accord mais en l'occurrence *nombreux* ne fait en rien partie de ce que vous appelez les adjectifs indéfinis. Il se comporte tout simplement comme un adjectif qualificatif au même titre que *sombre*. Ce qui fait de cette réponse un problème par rapport à la question.